# Problem webcam Ubuntu 14.10, please help me! :(

Tags: webcam

The Cheese Webcam Booth this not working properly when I try to take a picture, she calls usually can capitar images, but when I click to take the picture, it is saved all black, no image only black background. .. detail, when I try to record videos the program works normally and saves perfectly, but photos do not :(
I tried using other software and can take pictures in them, as the kamerka for example, but none pleased me could help me with the cheese, some configuration, directories? already tried to uninstall and delete all settings and reinstall but nothing works !!

note: if you do not solve the problem can you recommend other camera programs that will appeal, I do not speak English well, forgive my mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I lied the link that you actually want which actually is good is https://obsproject.com/download#linux open broadcasting software obs

Comment: Hi, in this case you possibly should edit your first answer instead of adding a new one.